# When Promise state become rejected or resolved

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 1000);
});

// reject runs the second function in .then
promise.then(
  result => alert(result), // doesn't run
  error => alert(error) // shows "Error: Whoops!" after 1 second
);
```

In the above code snippets even though I am calling reject but promise state is coming as resolved but when I am removing `error => alert(error)` from `promise.then` then I am getting promise state as rejected 
If one is calling reject then promise state should be rejected not resolved am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise that is resolved is not the original promise, but the promise returned by `then`. The original promise is indeed rejected, and you can verify that by `console.log(promise)`. But because you chained `then` [it returns another promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) ..

> **Return value** [of `then`]
>
> A `Promise` in the **pending** status. The handler function
>   (`onFulfilled` or `onRejected`) then gets called **asynchronously** (as soon
>   as the stack is empty). After the invocation of the handler function,
>   if the handler function:
>
> - returns a value, the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with the
>     returned value as its value;
> - *doesn't return anything, the promise returned by `then` gets **resolved** with an `undefined` value*;
> - throws an error, the promise returned by then gets rejected with the thrown
>     error as its value;
>
> ...

This second point is what applies to your case. You can verify that by observing that
 `Promise.reject().then(undefined, ()=>{})`
returns a promise that gets resolved with an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can also handle Promises in "then-catch" fashion like below

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => reject('Error'));
});

promise
  .then(result => console.log('Result ', result)) 
  .catch(error => console.log('This is Error message -', error))
```

Comment: `then` accepts two arguments - one for success callback and the other for a rejection callback. Using it a valid way of dealing with Promise rejection.

Comment: A promise should have exception handling mechanism. That is why we have `.catch`, the control goes to `.catch` when an exception is thrown from the promise  body. if you call `resolve` the control goes to the first executor argument of `.then` and if you call `reject`, then it goes to the second argument of `.then`. So I think we should have both `then` and `catch`

Answer (score 0):

The final status of the promise is also rejected in your case. 
Try console.log(promise);
It has nothing to do with error => alert(error)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems to work correctly both on Chrome and Firefox - the Promise was rejected as expected. `reject` function marks the Promise as rejected - you can then react upon that rejection either by passing a callback function into a second argument of `then` or by using the `catch` method. Both approaches are correct.

If you are encountering any unexpected behaviour, verify that you are not using some faulty polyfill that replaces the original `Promise` object.

Reference: [Promise.prototype.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), [Promise.prototype.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)